# What are the subfield of $\mathbb{C}$ that is $\mathbb{Q}$-isomorphic to the following

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, galois-theory

> What are the subfields of $\mathbb{C}$ that are $\mathbb{Q}$-isomorphic to $\mathbb{Q}[\sqrt[6]{3}]$?

I'm guessing also 3. Itself and the 2 primitive 6th roots of unity, $e^{2\pi i/6}, e^{2\pi i\cdot5/6}$ multiplied to it.

Am I right ?

Any help or insight is appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because $X^6-3$ is irreducible over $\mathbb{Q}$, the embeddings $\mathbb{Q}[\sqrt[6]{3}] \to \mathbb{C}$ are in bijection with the roots of $X^6-3$ and so there are $6$ embeddings, corresponding to $\sqrt[6]{3} \mapsto \sqrt[6]{3}\omega^k$, for $k=0,\dots,5$, where $\omega$ is a primitive $6$-root of unity.

Let $L_k = \mathbb{Q}[\sqrt[6]{3}\omega^k]$. Because $\omega^3=-1$, we have $\omega^4=-\omega$ and $\omega^5=-\omega^2$, and so $L_0=L_3$,
 $L_1=L_4$ and $L_2=L_5$.

So, yes, you're right: there are exactly $3$ subfields of $\mathbb{C}$ isomorphic to $\mathbb{Q}[\sqrt[6]{3}]$.